# How to change some content in slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

I need to make a slider and only some of the div's need to be changed.

```html
<div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 mb-12 left">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 mb-12 gold-box">Moss'tan sonra...</div>
    <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 mb-12 description">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren.
      <div class="buttons">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-fill-primary"><i class="fa fa-caret-left"></i></button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-fill-primary"><i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 mb-12 image">
      <img src="assets/images/index/before.png" alt="Before Car" />
      <div class="bottom-text before">Öncesi</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 mb-12 image">
      <img src="assets/images/index/after.png" alt="After Car" />
      <div class="bottom-text after">Sonrası</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you see here, there are two buttons on the buttons div and when it is clicked (and automatically) description and the image div need to be changed.

I am already using slick slider in my project but I dont know how to change some of the content.

Comment: are u saying that on `onclick ` event of button, the src attribute of img should change, you can give class to img tags to target it.

Comment: I want to change lorem ipsum part (description div) and before car image and after car image when it's clicked the button & in every 5 seconds

Comment: Chcek your question, specifically check the snippet - it's very, very broken :)